# How to find the location of two consecutive spaces in a string

Tags: c++, string

I want to check if my string has two consecutive spaces in it.  What's the easiest way to find out?

Comment: I agree with @Jon Winstanley... by space do you mean ASCII character 32 (0x20), or do you mean white-space in general?

Comment: I think just it's just whitespace.  Strings don't see whitespace and spaces as the same thing?

Answer (score 7):

Use the `find()` method of `std::string`. It returns the special constant `std::string::npos` if the value was not found, so this is easy to check for:

```
if (myString.find("  ") != std::string::npos)
{
  cerr << "double spaces found!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>

bool are_there_two_spaces(const std::string& s) {
    if (s.find("  ") != std::string::npos) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why explicit returns of boolean values? If you want to have a function, consider just returning the result of the comparison directly. It's boolean by definition.

Comment: `return (s.find("  ") != std::string::npos);` should do. However, this'll be optimized out I guess.

Comment: @unwind: I know that, but since the asker didn't know about this function, I tried to write the example as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This one of Jon Skeet's fave topics: [see this presentation](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Make search for "  " in the string.
```

Comment: Oh, you aren't familiar with English++?

Answer (score 0):

Using C:

```
#include <cstring>
...
addr = strstr (str, "  ");
...
```

Comment: If you're going to use `strstr`, you should use `str.c_str()`, because it takes a `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "foo  bar";
int i = s.find("  ");
if(i != string::npos)
   cout << "Found at: " << i << endl;
```